# hive standalone metastore reading avro data with schema not working

Tags: hive, avro, hive-serde

we have usecase of presto hive accessing s3 file present in avro format.
When we try to use standalone hive-metastore and read this avro data using external table ,we are getting issue SerDeStorageSchemaReader  class not found issue

```
    MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.SerDeStorageSchemaReader class not found)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.getClass(JavaUtils.java:54)
```

We understand this error is coming because SerDeStorageSchemaReader class is not available in standalone-metastore.

i want to understand can be run hive-metastore without using hive/hadoop  or there is any other option too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standalone hive doesnt support avro. we need to install full hadoop plus hive version and start only hive metastore to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I managed to tweak Hive Standalone to work with Avro files and S3 by doing the following:

1. In the *metastore-site.xml* file I added the following:

   ```
    <property>
    <name>metastore.storage.schema.reader.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.SerDeStorageSchemaReader</value> </property>
   ```
2. I added the following jars to *${HIVE_HOME}/lib/*

- hive-metastore-${METASTORE_VERSION}.jar (full hive version)
- hive-common-${METASTORE_VERSION}.jar
- hive-serde-${METASTORE_VERSION}.jar

3. I created the table like this:

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  table_xyz (col1 INT, col2 INT) WITH (format = 'AVRO', partitioned_by = ARRAY['col1', col2], external_location = 's3a://my_bucket/path/blah', avro_schema_url = 's3a://mybucket/avro_file_schema.avsc');